# IPsec и GRE на Pfsense

Tags: сеть, ip, pfsense

Есть два роутера Pfsense `xxx.xxx.xxx.28`  и `xxx.xxx.xxx.27`, за ними локалки `192.168.110.0/24`  и `192.168.111.0/24`. Задача поднять между локальными сетями GRE туннель под IPSEC. Туннель готов( `10.0.0.1 - 10.0.0.2`)но при включении IPSEC во вкладке Status->IPsec, пакеты  пересылаемых файлов не отображаются то есть ощущение, что траффик проходит совершенно не по туннелю . При этом если сделать `traceroute` между машинами из локальных сетей, то пакеты в траффике IPsec отображаются, но только входящие, пришедшие в ответ.  То есть на локальном PFsense отобразятся 3 входящих пакета, а на удаленном 3 исходящих. Все, больше траффика в IPsec не видно, ни от пинга ни от пересылаемых файлов.

Comment: И в чем ваш вопрос конкретно заключается?

Comment: Работает ли туннель. Правильно ли он настроен?